# Cannot see two tables with the same name

Tags: postgresql

I have two non-`public` schemas in one database. A table named `"foo"` exists in both schemas and I can execute all necessary DDL & DML commands against both. However, when I execute `\d`, I cannot see both of them. What gives?

#### Repro

```sql
create schema a;
create schema b;

create table a.foo (i int);
create table b.foo (i int);

set search_path = "$user", public, a, b;
```

In [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

```
postgres=# \d
            List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |   Owner
--------+-----------+-------+------------
 a      | foo       | table | pvandivier
(1 row)
```

---

I `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on` to extract the underlying query run by `\d` and moved the relevant lines from the `WHERE` clause into the `SELECT` to examine the differences between the two table objects.

```sql
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'partitioned table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'partitioned index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner",
  pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid),
  n.nspname,
  c.relkind
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE n.nspname IN ('a','b')
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Running this query reveals...

```
 Schema | Name | Type  |   Owner    | pg_table_is_visible | nspname | relkind
--------+------+-------+------------+---------------------+---------+---------
 a      | foo  | table | pvandivier | t                   | a       | r
 b      | foo  | table | pvandivier | f                   | b       | r
```

The relevant difference appears to be the output of [`pg_table_is_visible()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html). But why should it return "`False`" when asking if `b.foo` is visible?

> Why is `pg_table_is_visible()` returning `False` for a table I have access to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept `is_visible` here appears to mean "*the **first** one you see in the* `search_path`"; and **not** "*can you see it*". You can demonstrate this for yourself by changing the ordering of schemas in the `search_path`.

```
postgres=# set search_path = "$user", public, b, a;
SET
postgres=# \d
            List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |   Owner
--------+-----------+-------+------------
 b      | foo       | table | pvandivier
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Note that `b.foo` is returned when `b` is listed first in the `search_path`. This is supported as well by the output of the previous query re-run in the same `search_path`.

```
 Schema | Name | Type  |   Owner    | pg_table_is_visible | nspname | relkind
--------+------+-------+------------+---------------------+---------+---------
 a      | foo  | table | pvandivier | f                   | a       | r
 b      | foo  | table | pvandivier | t                   | b       | r
(2 rows)
```

We can now clearly see that `pg_table_is_visible()` is `True` for `b` and `False` for `a`. Therefore "`is_visible`" is an indicator of current accessibility and *not* an indicator of whether a relation exists.

Note that attempting to determine visibility of a non-existent object has a different set of behaviours.

```
postgres=# -- attempting to get the oid of a non-existent object
postgres=# select 'c.foo'::regclass;
ERROR:  schema "c" does not exist
LINE 1: select 'c.foo'::regclass;
               ^
postgres=# select 'bar'::regclass::oid;
ERROR:  relation "bar" does not exist
LINE 1: select 'bar'::regclass::oid
               ^
postgres=# -- passing an oid for a non-existent object returns NULL
postgres=# select pg_table_is_visible((random() * 1e7)::int::oid);
 pg_table_is_visible
---------------------

(1 row)

postgres=#
```

---

You can also read this somewhat in source at src/backend/catalog/namespace.c. I'm not fluent in C, but the following citations appear to support this reasoning.

- [pg_table_is_visible()](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7559d8ebfa11d98728e816f6b655582ce41150f3/src/backend/catalog/namespace.c#L4382) references `RelationIsVisible`

```c
Datum
pg_table_is_visible(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    Oid         oid = PG_GETARG_OID(0);

    if (!SearchSysCacheExists1(RELOID, ObjectIdGetDatum(oid)))
        PG_RETURN_NULL();

    PG_RETURN_BOOL(RelationIsVisible(oid));
}
```

- [`RelationIsVisible`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7559d8ebfa11d98728e816f6b655582ce41150f3/src/backend/catalog/namespace.c#L694) reveals the following code comments just above the return logic

```c
/*
 * If it is in the path, it might still not be visible; it could be
 * hidden by another relation of the same name earlier in the path. So
 * we must do a slow check for conflicting relations.
 */
```